# JPA and EclipseLink : best strategies for check of a membership in XXXtoMany relationships

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Sometimes in ORMs (like EclipseLink) when there is a relation between two entities like

```
public class ContactGroup {

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

a simple check (I am talking in the context of the example) if a User is a member of 
a ContactGroup is required. I want to do it without loading of all members like

boolean isMemeber = contactGroup.getMembers().contains(user);

I made next :

```
SELECT contactGroup FROM ContactGroup contactGroup " + 
"WHERE contactGroup.id = ?1 " +
"AND ?2 MEMBER OF contactGroup.users"
```

and in my DAO layer check if contactGroup is NULL or NO. In this case I avoid loading of all users just for that simple check.

My question is: do you think that is a good strategy to do that ? If not, can you give some more info or other strategy ?

I was googling but I was no found nice results.

Thanks in advance, 
Simeon

Comment: Have you checked that the use of `contains` really does provoke a load of all the members? a JPA provider should be able to answer that question by loading only the IDs, which is relatively cheap. I have a vague memory of reading that Hibernate actually does this.

Comment: In fact yeas, as I read EclipseLInk docs, when there is an accessing (in our case - with calling of contactGroup.getUsers()), then loading of related entities is performed. I know that in Hibernate there is EXTRA lazy fetching which allows no initialization of related entities when you call size(), contains() and isEmpty(), but for now I haven't met something related also for EclipseLink. If there is would be great

Comment: Okay, my compliments on your thoroughness. Shame EclipseLink doesn't do this!